# installing the ftw.blog add_on in Plone

Tags: plone

I am trying to incorporate the add-on "ftw.blog" into my fresh 4.3.2 plone installation (on linux).  As per the instructions, I have added "ftw.blog" to the eggs section of buildout.cfg.  Then I ran /bin/buildout.  This seemed to complete OK.  Now. as per the instructions, I am to "install ftw.blog in portal_setup".  But it is not obvious how to do so.  Can anyone instruct me as to how to install ftw,blog in portal_setup?  Thanks...

Comment: I'll update the readme of `ftw.blog` for abetter install instruction. I also opened a issue on github. https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.blog/issues/42

Answer (score 4):

Most likely a typo, not 'portal_setup', but 'portal_quickinstaller', is the usual way to activate an add-on.

Go to http://somedomain.org:8080/yourPloneSiteId/portal_quickinstaller (via ZMI) or  http://somedomain.org:8080/yourPloneSiteId//prefs_install_products_form (via Plonesite-UI), to activate the add-on.

You might want to inform the authors about it. If you do so, please leave a note about it here in a comment.

Comment: Thanks Ida.  I have used the prefs_install_products_form and activated ftw.blog.  I have not any experience using it yet.  Also, I did contact the owner of the web page "https://plone.org/products/ftw.blog", asking him to please clarify the installation instructions.

Comment: @user3502655: I take it, everything works now? Thanks for noticing the authors, Mathias has also created a ticket for it already (see comment at your quest).